# Removing multiple values from an array while preserving the size?

Tags: java

What's a clear way of doing this?

For a school assignment I have to make a class that holds an array of integers, and add methods that add to it, remove etc. Kinda like an ArrayList. The problem, however, is they want me to make a removeAll(int val) method that removes all occurrences of val from the list. For example, removeAll(4) would change

```
{1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4} to
{1, 2, 6, 3, 6, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0}.
```

For my regular remove() method, I'm using Apache Common's Lang ArrayUtils class to remove the element. Removing all elements with it doesn't work fully, for some reason. My current plan of attack is to find out how many times val appears in the array, and then call ArrayUtils.remove() that many times. But it gives me weird results, for instance shrinking the array. Any other way to attack this? I can't use ArrayList supposedly, and I doubt they'll check if I am or not, but it would be nice to figure out how to do this the way they want me to.

Comment: If it's homework, you likely shouldn't be using ArrayUtils, even if you would use it "in real life".

Comment: @pst I know, I should probably spend more time with arrays and get comfortable using them, but arrays are really, really confusing to me when I get into problems like this.

Comment: are java arrays mutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the array shrinks when using [`ArrayUtils.remove`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28boolean%5b%5d,%20int%29) is that a new array *without that index* is returned: the size of the result array is one less than the size of the input array. Also note that it takes an *index* and not a *value to remove*, so `result = ArrayUtils.remove(input, 4)` removes the 5th element, not the element with the value of `4`.

Here is a simple O(n) approach to achieve the desired keep-the-same-size-array semantics. Try it out on paper to verify how it works or that I didn't mess something up bad ;-)

1. Iterate through the array and keep tracking of the "reading index" and "writing index" (both initially at the start of the array).
2. For each element at "reading index", if the element matches the element to remove, increase the "reading index" (but not the "writing index"): the point is to write over the old value to remove.
3. Copy the value from the "reading index" to the "writing index".
4. Increase the "reading index" and "writing index", and repeat from #2 until #5 is satisfied.
5. When the "reading index" is at the end of the array, write 0's from "writing index" to end of the array as the stuff in those indices has already been copied.

There are variations of this that require less moves if the order does not need to be preserved, and a slight optimization to avoid moves until needed. (This would also work for a plain `removeOne` with a modified stop condition.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

From a simplistic perspective I'd just iterate through the indeces of the array and check for the presence of the value.

If you really wanted to get complicated you could "store" the value of the array and map it to an index so you would know which indexes a value is in.

But I'd probably go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is homework ;-)
What you may want to do is create a new Array, copy all elements into it that are unequal to the argument given and then fill up the Array with zeros to match the length of the original Array.